# Rotary phone with numbers and letters

Tags: no-computers, puzzle-creation

I am going to organise a quest for teenagers.

I have a vintage phone like below:

[image]

I am looking for ideas how to use the rotary phone with
numbers 1,2, ..., 9, 0 and letters
A, B, C, F, H, I, K, L, M, R.

My attempt is:
to use a  "A1Z26" cipher (in my case A1R0), for instance,
3188 - CALL, 2188 - BALL, 619 - I AM, 4188 - FALL, 7688 - KILL, 2688 - BILL.

What is an alternative to the substitution cipher?

Comment: I found your phone! https://www.translatetheweb.com/?from=de&to=en&ref=SERP&dl=en&rr=UC&a=https%3a%2f%2fwww.wasser.de%2ftelefon-alt%2fforum%2findex.pl%3fjob%3dthema%26tnr%3d100000000009272  https://en.todocoleccion.net/phones/antiguo-telefono-mix-genest-aleman-baquelita~x96547447

Comment: Some interesting longer words available from those letters are *blackmail* and *armchair*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get a bit more excitement from the letters if you assign each number to a range, albeit an irregular one.

So 1=A, 2=B, 3=C,D,E, 4=F,G, 5=H, 6=I,J, 7=K, 8=L, 9=M,N,O,P,Q, and 0=R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z.

So for example PUZZLING STACK EXCHANGE becomes 90008694 00137 30351943.

To decode, reverse the process. With some of the letters fixed, guessing the others should be easy enough.

Comment: If the phone has actual letters marked on it, then using a _different_ correspondence between letters and digits seems likely to be really confusing...

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan; fixed - it was very early...